# In $Z_5 [x]$, the monic GCD of the polynomials $(x+[4])(x+[3])$ and $([3]x + [2])(x + [3])$ is $(x + [3])$

Tags: ring-theory, polynomials

**True or False**

In $Z_5 [x]$, the monic GCD of the polynomials $(x+[4])(x+[3])$ and $([3]x + [2])(x + [3])$ is $(x + [3])$.

**my solution :**

$([3]x+[2])$ is $[3](x+[4])$ therefore gcd is  $(x+[4])(x+[3])$

therefore answer is false

**my doubt**

How to solve using factorization method.

also what is meaning of $Z_5 [x]$ (no coefficient is greater than 5??)

Answer (score 1):

In $F[x]$ ($F$ a field) the polynomials $x - a$ are always primes.

Answer (score 0):

$\rm\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\ \ \ gcd(f(x)\,(x\!+\!4),\,f(x)g(x)) &\,=\, &\rm f(x)\,gcd(x\!+\!4,\,g(x))\\
 & =\,&\rm f(x)\,(x\!+\!4)\ \ \ if\ \ \ g(-4)= 0\\
 & =\, &\rm f(x)\qquad\quad\ \  if\ \ \ g(-4)\ne 0, \ \ \ by\  the\  Factor\ Theorem \end{eqnarray}$

**Note** $\ $ Yours is $\rm\:f(x) = x\!+\!3,\ g(x)=3x\!+\!2,\:$ so $\rm\:g(-4)\equiv g(1)\equiv 3\!+\!2\equiv 0.\:$ I presume $\,Z_5\,$ denotes $\,\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z = $ [integers modulo $5,\,$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) so $\,Z_5[x]= \,$ ring of polynomials whose coefficients are integers mod $5$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Is it clearer now?